# Service Timer keep alive forever

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I building a service application in c#. i'm trying to make my action (array) with timer every 2 second. but my timer keep die after my function call finished.

my Onstart:

```
   ...
   Alaram  Fi = new Alaram();
   Fi.AgentStart();
   GC.KeepAlive(Fi);
   ...
```

My Alaram class:

```
    public void AgentStart()
    {
        ...
        int i = 0;
        Timer[] timers = new Timer[count];

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            timers[i] = new Timer(coba, myReader["DeviceId"], 0, 2000);
            i++;
        }
        GC.KeepAlive(timers);

     }
```

My Action:

```
 public void coba(object id)
 {
        ...

        int sec = Convert.ToInt32((string)myCommand.ExecuteScalar());
        sec++;

        myCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Roles  SET  Value ='" + sec.ToString() + "' WHERE   Name = 'Fire" + id.ToString() + "'", ibmsConnect);
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        ...
  }
```

my timer only execute maximum 36 times after that my timer didn't execute anymore. I need it to keep live until the service is stop

anyone have idea why my timer keep stoping tick??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GC.KeepAlive` will only prevent aggressive garbage collecting on the timers for the scope in which they are declared (or stored), which would be the array in the `AgentStart` method. Once the array and the timers go out of scope (when the method is done executing) they will begin to be collected by garbage collection.

You will need to declare the array in a location where it will stay in scope. One way to do this is by marking the array as static and placing it on the class level . Next instantiate the timers you assign to the array in a static constructor of the class. This should keep them alive.

Comment: do you have suggestion so it can live forever?? i also have my class keep alive, is it enough?

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation for `KeepAlive`:

> This method references the obj parameter, making that object ineligible for garbage collection from the start of the routine to the point, in execution order, where this method is called. Code this method at the end, not the beginning, of the range of instructions where obj must be available.
>
> The KeepAlive method performs no operation and produces no side effects other than extending the lifetime of the object passed in as a parameter.

In other words, `KeepAlive` simply does nothing, but references the variable, so that the GC will not collect it *before* the `KeepAlive` call. This is useful for local variables that need to stick around until they go out of scope. Here is a simple example:

```
void DoSomething()
{
    Timer myTimer = ...;
    // long-running operation
    GC.KeepAlive(myTimer);
}
```

Without the `KeepAlive`, the method could be optimized to the point where the Timer is collected midway through the long-running operation.

Simply put, `KeepAlive` does not keep the object around after the call, only before.

To keep the object from being collected, you need to keep a reference to it. This can be simply achieved by storing it in a field of the class (as long as the class instance itself doesn't go out of scope).